# FCM - How to subscribe to topics after migrating to HTTPv1

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to migrate from FCM Legacy API to FCM V1 API. I manage to send notifications to device token perfectly using FCM V1 API, but I could not figure out how to subscribe user to topics.

I'm using googleapis IID API for this `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/<DEVICE TOKEN HERE>/rel/topics/<TOPIC NAME HERE>`.

Earlier in Legacy API we had Server Key that I use to send in headers like this `{Authorization: key=<SERVER KEY>}`, but as after HTTP V1 API we don't have server key anymore.

**Things I tried:**

1. I tried sending API token in Authorization like `{Authorization: Bearer <API TOKEN HERE>}`   that I'm using for sending Push Notification to device token as it is generated using google API PHP client.
2. I tried sending API Key in authorization like `{Authorization: key=<API KEY HERE>}`, but no luck.

Getting 401 unauthorized error in response using above mentioned ways.

Can anyone guide me if I'm missing something or doing something wrong?

I am using PHP as a back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Set `access_token_auth` to `true` in your header.

Eg.

> POST [https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/`DEVICE_TOKEN`/rel/topics/`TOPIC_NAME`](https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/%60DEVICE_TOKEN%60/rel/topics/%60TOPIC_NAME%60)
>
> Authorization: Bearer `API_TOKEN_HERE`
>
> access_token_auth: true